# How to delete custom metrics Application insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

How can I delete custom metrics I've created from Azure Portal Application Insights? Is it any query you can make to delete all the data?

I've created the metrics from C# code.

Comment: take a look at this [purge api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/components/purge). But it does not delete them immediately.

Comment: If the answer works for you, please help mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: It could work, but I need it faster than 1-2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [purge api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/components/purge) for deleting data. There is a table parameter if you want to delete data from a special table. But remember that the data is not deleted immediately, there are some days delay.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

REST API PURGE is your friend if you want to delete any data from azure application insights. You can delete the data from any table of application insights based on timestamp of your choice. Refer for more details - https://sanganakauthority.blogspot.com/2019/06/how-to-delete-or-purge-azure.html